# What are some of the ways of identifying trade-offs between security & privacy?

Tags: privacy, threat-mitigation

Privacy can mean different things to people. Protecting one's identity from autocratic regimes to ex-boyfriend/girlfriends/partners. Threat modeling goes some way in understanding actors and the potential options in mitigating these.

Guides such as [Security in a Box](https://securityinabox.org/en/), [Privacy Tools](https://www.privacytools.io/), [Privacy Test](https://privacytests.org/)s, [Privacy Guides](https://www.privacyguides.org/) offer techniques and tools in protecting privacy and against digital/analog threats to those who may not be experts in either privacy and/or security.

While these help simplify complex topics into a series to things to do and not do, what are some of the ways of identifying and measuring trade-offs between security & privacy?

As an example, if a user chooses to use Google Chrome because [it's perceived to have a stronger security model](https://madaidans-insecurities.github.io/firefox-chromium.html) than say Mozilla Firefox, it may reduce the privacy posture unless potentially additional considerations are implemented.

For instance, the browser [comparison](https://eylenburg.github.io/browser_comparison.htm) suggests that Mozilla has native tracking protection but Google Chrome doesn't. How does a user identify and measure these trade-offs?

Comment: What do you mean by trade-off? We speak about trade-off when two things lead to **opposite** effects. Do you mean that more security means less privacy and less security means more privacy? That would be nonsense. Actually, one of the goals of security is providing privacy. And to get more privacy, you need more security. Try to formulate your question in other words.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is asking. Privacy and security are not necessarily mutually exclusive, depending on threat model.

Comment: @mentallurg, the definition of a trade-off in this context is if a user for example opts to adopt Google Chrome as it's perceived to have a stronger security model than say Mozilla Firefox, it may reduce the privacy posture unless other additional considerations are implemented. The question I'm asking is how does someone identify and measure these so that they are aware that extra actions may need to be taken.

Comment: @fenixleon: Then it is **incorrect** to speak about "security vs privacy". Security means the whole that **includes** privacy. In your specific case you can formulate it as *"trade-off between availability, integrity, authenticity on one side and confidentiality on the other side"* or *"trade-off between different security aspects"* or similar. But opposing security and privacy is incorrect.

Comment: @fenixleon: The article you linked has the same **problem**. At the beginning the author **changes the meaning of the word security** by removing privacy from security. The author says that the article is actually about *"resistance to exploitation"*. If *that* is your question, then please change the title to *"resistance to exploitation vs privacy"*.

Comment: @mentallurg, the question isn't intended to be security vs privacy. It's about striking a balance between security and privacy (as it's with confidentiality, integrity and safety) however having ways to understand the trade-offs. For example, CCTV cameras may improve security as it increases the ability to identify threats. At the same time, it may decrease privacy as people are monitored.  The question is asking if yes, what are the ways to identify and measure these.

Comment: @fenixleon: You are using wrong wording again. You cannot say "security and privacy", because privacy is **part** of security. It is like to say "animals and cats", or "birds and eagles"   CCTV **do not** improve security. They can improve only **some part** of security (e.g. can improve physical security). But they violate confidentiality (or privacy in your words) and thus CCTV **worsen** security.

Comment: Security is as much as a part of privacy as privacy is of security. This isn't drawing parallels. You mention that CCTV doesn't improve security and only aspects of it. If we use that an example, how did you identify and measure it worsens security and erodes privacy? What did you consider in coming to the conclusion it does not improve security overall? Did this include scenarios that the benefits of physical security outweigh the decrease in privacy?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical example is of course content inspection (by nation, company, school, etc). This goes back to the pre-computer era; if your country's postal service is opening letters and packages to inspect them (maybe for state secrets, maybe for illegal materials or weapons) then this is a clear win for national security, but a huge loss for personal privacy.

The equivalent happened in the telephone era with "wiretapping"; both active eavesdropping, and passive "metadata collection" of who called who and for how long.

The equivalent is happening today with things like SMS, email, and browser traffic. Take for example, companies that want to monitor all traffic on their network to detect and block malware entering the network and corporate secrets leaving the network. Win for security at the expense of all employee privacy.

---

There is probably a similar story with regards to anti-virus and other invasive endpoint monitoring tools. Even uploading the file hashes of files on your system to a anti-virus server may allow someone to track, for example, what you have installed on your computer.

---

There is also usage of "cloud services". Gmail undoubtedly does a better job of security than I would if I ran my own mail server, but that comes at the direct privacy cost of allowing Google to mine my emails for advertizing purposes.

Similar story for password managers: a cloud-based password manager is better for security than trying to sync it across all my devices myself -- and especially so if you consider Availability to be part of security -- but that comes at the expense of privacy, for example an attacker monitoring my network traffic could see that I always have traffic to lastpass and to my bank at the same time.

Comment: what did you use to identify and measure for example Google doing a better job at security and the impact it has to privacy that users other than specialists can reference so that they can make an informed decision about the choices they make? For instance, it is it sufficient to take the information from [Privacy Tests](https://privacytests.org/) at face value that Brave does a better job with privacy and thus security if I cite @mentallurg's comment `Actually, one of the goals of security is providing privacy. And to get more privacy, you need more security`?

Comment: @fenixleon Sounds like you're asking me to write a fully-cited academic paper for you.

Comment: I'm seeking clarification. For instance, if one of ways of identifying and measuring was to use resources such as [Privacy Tests](https://privacytests.org/), it's potential reference and a benchmark in the decision making process. You may also say that you did X and Y to complement the resources. Maybe another way to ask the question is if you had to choose between Chrome and Brave as a non-security user, what would you do to come to a decision?